# Azure Function App to local on premis service connection

Tags: azure, vpn

Virtual machine can access internal network address (through VPN connection) but Function App can't.

Any ideas where to start (I have already read existing Q&A but no help found)? Vnet integration is configured with same Virtual Network where the VM resides... but still no access to internal on prem server :(

**Hybrid connection** is working as well but it need to work with VPN!

Comment: Do you have integrated Functions with an Azure virtual network? Do you troubleshoot it via following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options#troubleshooting)?

Comment: Yes. VNet Integration is on. Tcpping cannot resolve target machine. VM can access it with no problem. VM and Function in same Virtual Network

Comment: Does the Azure VM access the on-premise server with internal IP? Does the function app access the on-premise server with internal IP instead of hostname?

Comment: No problem with VM - it access OnPrem with IP. Function app does not

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid Connections should work on on premise web services.

Best ensure that you're NOT using the consumption plan for the Azure Function. I had best performance using the Premium plan. More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options

Make sure you specify the correct port. (I.E. port 80 -> http and port 443 -> https). Create the new hybrid connection in your azure function via the networking tab. From there go to your on prim computer and download the hybrid connection manager there.

Note that you should use **FQDN** (i.e. www.nameofmyservice.<>.com) for your hybrid connection so that your request can understand the dns routing.

I had a problem where I would change the port number in azure but it doesn't reflect on the Hybrid Connection Manager. I removed the connection and re added the connection and everything works just fine.

For more information on how to create a hybrid connection can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections

Comment: As I wrote - Hybrid Connection works! No problem here :)

Comment: Including the companies' VPN for Azure Functions? Sorry if I misunderstood the question!